# The background screen become black and no control of mine on this when i fetch the data from the table in android

Tags: android, android-layout

The data is fetched and i show it in a textview. But the problem is when the table data is shown the background screen become black and we don't have any control over it.the code is below which i am using

```
public class high_score extends Activity{
SQLiteDatabase mydatabase=null;
String Data="";
String TableName="users";
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.high_score);


  //  RelativeLayout main=new RelativeLayout(this);

    RelativeLayout main=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main);
    main.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.highestlevel_menu));

    try
    {
        mydatabase=this.openOrCreateDatabase("testdata", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        Cursor c=mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+TableName, null);
        int column1=c.getColumnIndex("name");
        int column2=c.getColumnIndex("user_score");
        c.moveToFirst();
        if(c!=null)
        {   
            do
            {
                String Name=c.getString(column1);
                int Score=c.getInt(column2);
                Data=Data+Name+"               "+Score+"\n";
                System.out.println("name"+Name+" score"+Score);
            }while(c.moveToNext());
            TextView display_data=new TextView(this);
            display_data.setText(Data);
            setContentView(display_data);
            main.addView(display_data, null);


        }

         /*TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tv.setText(Data);
        setContentView(tv);*/

    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("ERROR","ERROR" ,ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(mydatabase!=null)
            mydatabase.close();
    }

    main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent start = new Intent(high_score.this,KtriviaActivity.class);
            startActivity(start);
            finishActivity(0);
        }
    });
}
}
```

My layout code is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"

android:id="@+id/main" >
```

By this table data is fetched and shown but the other things not working.Please help me in this i need to finish it as early as possible.

Comment: Could you please post your layout `high_score`, too

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    
    android:id="@+id/main" >

    
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: Please not as a comment, edit your question. And remove the `setContentView(display_data)`.

Comment: this is my layout which i shown in this comment box above

Comment: i added the layout code and when i remaove the setContentView(display_data); and run the code then  the screen appear normally with the background image but the table data not shown

Comment: are you fetching large amount of data from database?

Comment: only two columns have near bout 10 rows which contaion the name of the user and his score thats it.

Comment: Yes i have solved this problem. I have used 
main.addView(display_data,null);and setContentView(Data);
in my code. when i replace this with

main.addView(display_data); and setContentView(main);

it worked fine and show the data on my screen with no such issues. 

thanks to everyone who help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some minor issues.

1. you check your cursor for null after you called `c.moveToFirst()`
2. Creating new objects in a while loop is a bad idea (I mean Name and Score)
3. You should be sure that your query works, so make an else case where you display in your TextView that no results were found.

Basically your TextView usage seems to be correct (just checked that it works without LayoutParams, too). I guess that somehow your database doesn't return the expected values. You should start debugging and check in which statement your program goes.

Do you see your `System.out.println`?

Comment: yes i checked it by using the System.out.println and my database return the data every time. There is no problem in that. But the problem is to show that data over the textview with the existing background which terns into black when the data comes on that page. if remove the setContentView(display_data); then background is ok but data is not shown.

Comment: no prob WarrenFaith. thanks for your concern and to look at my problem.

Comment: Yes i have solved this problem. I have used 
main.addView(display_data,null);and setContentView(Data);
in my code. when i replace this with

main.addView(display_data); and setContentView(main);

it worked fine and show the data on my screen with no such issues. 

thanks to everyone who help me in this.